# What is the importance of "throw" keyword when already "throws" and try-catch block are available in JAVA?

Tags: java

A practical and simple example will be very helpful.When already try-catch block and throws keyword available ,is it worthy throwing an exception object manually?
**try-catch** block helps in catching an exception and displaying the information about that exception during Runtime right?
Can also anyone could tell the difference between  **"throw"** and **"throws"** keyword?

Comment: So you can "throw" something, unlike "return" something, it says, "throw this exception as something has gone wrong", where are "throws" says, "I might throw one or more exceptions, so you should be prepared"

Comment: The Online Java Tutorial on exceptions (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) has lots of examples.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Why not wrte an answer? :)

Comment: For your **custom throwables**. You may wany to throw it for other components of your application to capture and handle the error.

Comment: @synchronizer Because, to be frank, I shouldn't have to, there are so many tutorials on the subject it's ridiculous :P

Comment: Yeah, we SO need to bring back the GR close reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning is there in the words only.

Keyword  `throw` is a action word, for example `throw new Exception()` means the code is throwing an Exception, meaning if the execution control reaches this code, exception will be thrown. This is internal to a method.

Keyword `throws` is a declaration to the users of the method (code calling the method) that the method can throw an exception.

`try-catch` is an mechanism to try a code which can throw an exception and then catch the same if thrown.